# How to center a Label text in a StackLayout in QML?

Tags: qml

I have a Container which is a DockLayout and in this Container is a other one as a StackLayout. And there I have a label which I want to center, but I can't get it to work.

I need some help.

Here is a small overview of the structure:

```
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {
    }
    Container {
        id: cAnzeige
        Label {
            id: lblHeader
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XLarge
            text: "header"
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Top
        layout: StackLayout {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make the StackLayout fill the horizontal width:

```
horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.FILL
```

2) Make the Label centered:

```
horizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.CENTER
```

Answer (score 1):

`StackLayout` is excessive here. Using `DockLayout` in your case is enough:

```
Container {
    layout: DockLayout {
    }
    Container {
        id: cAnzeige
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        Label {
            id: lblHeader
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XLarge
            text: "header"
        }
    }
}
```